# Same exact monitors, same resolution set in display settings, still one does not fit the entire screen

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have two Acer H236HL connected to my desktop and am attempting to have an extended display.  When I go to display settings, both monitors have the recommended display resolution (1920 x 1080).   My issue is that one of the displays is extended to the corners of the screen while the other leaves margins on all sides, making an extended screen tricky if I attempt to use a program on both at the same time.  One is hooked up to the computer with DisplayPort to HDMI while the other is a straight DVI.  What could resolve this issue?

Comment: It's most likely overscan/underscan output settings in your display adapter driver.  What make/model is your display adapter and what OS is on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

Since the monitors are identical model, *switch them*, so the one now connected to DVI goes to HDMI and *vice versa*. This will determine if the issue is in the *monitor's settings*, or with the video output.

Second, consult the [Acer H236HL manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/455818/Acer-H236hl.html?page=18#manual) for screen width settings, e.g. *Wide Mode*. You might need to compensate the video output by adjusting display size.